GRUB menu does not appear after booting windows on dial boot machine
Sorry about this as I'm sure it's a FAQ.  I've already checked the suggestions on here.
I have a HP ProBook pre-installed. The first thing when I got the laptop - about 2 months ago - I did was install the current version of KUbuntu.  Everything went fine and I've had 2 lovely months of using it.
Today I had to boot Into Windows which was option 4 on my GRUB menu. That worked fine, and I shut down when I'd finished what I was doing.
However, when I boot up now I no longer get the GRUB menu appear, and the laptop goes straight into Windows 11.
Can anyone please point me at the instructions on how to re-instate the GRUB menu. I'm guessing it's still in place, but is being bypassed by the laptop during bootup.
I've tried various function keys at bootup to see if that helps, but I haven't managed to find anything.

Did Windows do an update? I may update & change to make Windows first in boot order. Or even update UEFI firmware resetting to defaults. Can you boot Ubuntu directly from UEFI one time boot menu? Is UEFI Secure boot on? Windows did an update and give SBAT error, and then you need shim 15.8 which once Noble is installed has. But older versions do not have that yet. Temporary fix is turn off UEFI Secure boot.

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi. Windows did not do an update. it simply booted up.
After some investigation I discovered that every time I boot up into Windows (From the GRUB2 menu), at some point the EUFI boot sequence gets updated with Windows being 1st.
If I go into the EUFI boot menu and change the boot order, I get back to having the GRUB2 menu appear.
Does anyone know how to prevent this, or how to easily put it back once it has happened?

I have not got to the bottom of this, but just as confusing, the problem has gone away. I have not amended anything, simply kept rebooting in to Windows and then into Kubuntu, and it started behaving.  Has now behaved after something line 10 reboots
